# Return another column value based on Max value from Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get a value from a column based on multiple other columns.  I am sure this is not that difficult, I am not sure how to go about it.  This is table I am pulling the data from.

|  | personid | coursename | termname | task | date | passingscore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | Algebra I | Semester 1 | Semester | 01/04/2022 | 1 |
| 2 | 123456 | Algebra I | Semester 1 | Progress | 01/02/2022 | 0 |
| 3 | 123456 | Algebra I | Semester 2 | Semester |  |  |
| 4 | 123456 | Algebra I | Semester 2 | Progress | 01/21/2022 | 1 |
| 5 | 123456 | English I | Semester 1 | Semester | 01/21/2022 | 1 |
| 6 | 123456 | English I | Semester 1 | Progress | 12/17/2021 | 1 |
| 7 | 123456 | English I | Semester 2 | Semester |  |  |
| 8 | 123456 | English I | Semester 2 | Progress | 01/22/2022 | 1 |
| 9 | 456255 | Geometry | Semester 1 | Progress | 12/15/2021 | 0 |
| 10 | 456255 | Geometry | Semester 1 | Semester | 01/12/2022 | 0 |
| 11 | 456255 | Geometry | Semester 2 | Progress | 01/25/2022 | 0 |
| 12 | 456255 | Geometry | Semester 2 | Semester | 01/31/2022 | 1 |
| 13 | 456255 | Physics 1 | Semester 2 | Semester | 01/06/2022 | 1 |
| 14 | 456255 | Physics 1 | Semester 2 | Progress | 12/12/2021 | 0 |
| 15 | 456255 | Physics 1 | Semester 2 | Semester |  |  |
| 16 | 456255 | Physics 1 | Semester 2 | Progress | 01/25/2022 | 1 |

So I would like to have them grouped by personid,coursename,termname and get the max from the date. Another way to look at it is I always want the most recent grade from each semester in each course for each student.  I would then like to have the passingscore column reported back

So this is what I want.

|  | personid | coursename | termname | passingscore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | Algebra I | Semester 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 123456 | Algebra I | Semester 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 123456 | English I | Semester 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 123456 | English I | Semester 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 456255 | Geometry | Semester 1 | 0 |
| 6 | 456255 | Geometry | Semester 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 456255 | Physics 1 | Semester 2 | 1 |
| 8 | 456255 | Physics 1 | Semester 2 | 1 |

This is what I have written. I have everything working, I just cannot figure out how to have it get the passing score.  I have a feeling it is something simple I am missing.

```
SELECT
    t.personid, t.coursename, t.termname,
    MAX(t.date) AS Recent,
FROM 
    table1 t
GROUP BY 
    t.personID, t.courseName, t.termName
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just add max(t.passingscore)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the most recent row per group which you can do using *row_number*

```
select t.personid, t.coursename, t.termname, t.Passingscore
from (
  select *, 
    Row_Number() 
      over (partition by personID, courseName, termName order by [date] desc) rn
  from t
)t
where rn=1;
```